# Retrieving Computer Names from AD in SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, active-directory

I want to get the computer names from Active Directory and display it in our SharePoint 2007 site without programming.

Can anybody check and help on this ?
Is it possible by configuring LDAP query at SSP level ?

Awaiting for the reply.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I dont think you can, without programming. 
You can upload a file with the computer names and display that.. no code needed.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this using the Business Data Catalog, not sure about it though.